# GCP: How can I set an Alert policy based on Logging programmatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

For CICD I am looking for a way to create an alert policy based on Cloud Logging programmatically instead of using the Cloud Console.

What is an easy way to do this?
I find the JSON that needs to be defined difficult to remember and I am prone to making errors there.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way getting a good setup of a JSON file needed to set your alert based on Cloud Logging is actually **first creating the Alert Policy in the Console**, like so:

[image: create alert based on logging]

After that you can find your alerting policy here:    
https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting/policies
Click on your policy and **download the Alert Policy in JSON format**.

[image: alert policy json download]

The JSON file will look something like this:

```json
{

  "displayName": "backup tableau ERROR test",
  "documentation": {
    "content": "when severity level >= WARNING for the tableau backup, deliver an email alert",
    "mimeType": "text/markdown"
  },
  "userLabels": {},
  "conditions": [
    {
      "displayName": "Log match condition",
      "conditionMatchedLog": {
        "filter": "resource.type = \"cloud_function\" OR resource.type = \"cloud_run_revision\" OR resource.type = \"cloud_scheduler_job\"\nresource.labels.service_name = \"backup-tableau\" OR resource.labels.function_name = \"backup-tableau\"  OR resource.labels.job_id = \"backup-tableau\"\n"
      }
    }
  ],
  "alertStrategy": {
    "autoClose": "604800s",
    "notificationRateLimit": {
      "period": "3600s"
    }
  },
  "combiner": "OR",
  "enabled": true,
  "notificationChannels": [
    "projects/your_project_name/notificationChannels/some_id_here"
  ],

}
```

**Finally you can then use this downloaded JSON to create your alert policy programmatically** as follows:
`gcloud alpha monitoring policies create --policy-from-file='your_alert_policy.json'`

See also:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts#policy_structure
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-api#api-create-policy